# Changes in ads.ini not reflected in arc' connection repository

Tags: database-connection, connection-string, uac, advantage-database-server

I just moved to win7 64bit from win xp.

When in XP, I can changed the content of ads.ini (add or change the connection), and the changes will be reflected in arc connection repository.

But now, nothing changes, the new database connection is not shown.

What should I check to make the changes in ads.ini can be shown in arc connection repository?

Answer (score 1):

Since the ARC is not Vista-ready yet ...

ARC is trying to store its ADS.ini in C:\Windows\ADS.ini, but Windows accepts the calls and redirects them to:

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\ADS.ini

Where "Username" is your username.

Just search the whole computer for ads.ini when in doubt.

Comment: To add a comment, with newer versions of the Advantage Clients you can set an environment variable adsini_path and place the ads.ini anywhere you want it. http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=090128-2126

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Actually I did the search, but somehow just the ads.ini in windows folder was found.